# No error from InvokeLambda request but the target lambda is never invoked

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function in AWS written in Go. This purpose of this lambda function is to trigger other lambda functions. The lambda function essentially looks like this:

```
func Handle(ctx context.Context) error {
    fmt.Println("Start")
    invokeInput := &lambda.InvokeInput{
        FunctionName: "MyFunctionName",
        Payload:        "{\"param\": \"value\"}",
        InvocationType: aws.String(lambda.InvocationTypeEvent),
    }
    output, err := t.lambdaClient.InvokeWithContext(ctx, invokeInput)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "Error invoking lambda")
    }

    if output.FunctionError != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Error invoking lambda: %s", *output.FunctionError)
    }
    fmt.Println("Success")
}
```

When I trigger this lambda through the AWS console, I see `Start` / `Success` log messages, but the lambda with name `MyFunctionName` is never invoked. There aren't any logs to begin debugging this. I believe the permissions on my lambda are correct. Does anyone know how to begin debugging this?